# Get last record from group data. MySql

Tags: mysql

Can anyone please help to get last record from the group.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JtCx.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.  
For SQL, an MCVE includes a few lines of `create table ... ` and `insert into table values ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
select * from t where col = 85 order by id desc limit 1
```

According to your comment, this should get  last records for every group:  (this assumes that `id` is unique and "last record" means record, with highest `id`)

```
select t.* from t 
inner join  (select max(id) as maxid  from t group by col) s
on t.id = s.maxid
```

Comment: Hi Sir, I have not only 85 id. I have number of ids in Group. So I want each last record record of that group data.

Comment: select * from t group by subscription_id order by id desc limit 1                      This query may work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much,  Oto Shavadze Sir

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the 1 row from mysql use 'limit' keyword.

[MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) supports the **LIMIT** clause to select a limited number of records, while Oracle uses ROWNUM.
Syntax:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
LIMIT number;
```

E.g.:
From your screenshot, subscription id is same for multiple id's you want to get last record which id is greater. The below query gets your result, grouped by subscription_id and ordered by id desc and limiting to 1 makes fetching only 1 row from database.

```
select * from tableName group by subscription_id order by id desc limit 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can used last() function.

**SELECT LAST(CustomerName) AS LastCustomer FROM Customers;**